# Referencing values in structures

Tags: android, c++, pointers

I am looking at opcommon.cpp in Android 4.3 and comparing it to the same file in 4.1.1

In both 4.1.1 and 4.3 the file Object.h defines the structure Instfield as

```
struct InstField : Field {
    int             byteOffset;
};
```

and the structure Field as

```
struct Field {
ClassObject*    clazz;          /* class in which the field is declared */
const char*     name;
const char*     signature;      /* e.g. "I", "[C", "Landroid/os/Debug;" */
u4              accessFlags;};
```

now my question is pretty simple:
given the declaration `InstField* ifield;`
opcommon has changed from using `ifield->field.name` in 4.1.1 to using `ifield->name` in 4.3
to retrieve the name variable. 
What is the difference and is either better? If not why would they change it?

I could not google this question because the -> was just ignored an I don't know the word to describe the operator. eg field.name is referencing a variable in a structure and -> is used to dereference pointers and does the same but what's it's name?
Another tiny question on terminology, is the InstField structural definition a wrapper or an extension?

Comment: My only explanation is that instead of an inheritance, maybe there used to be an aggregation, i.e. the `InstField` had a member `Field field;`?

Comment: Ok, ill edit to mention the deff is the same for both versions

Comment: Given that there is not a member field in the struct InstField, shouldn't the reference cause a compiler error? or will it only fail at runtime? I ask because the same reference occurs in a patch I have applied to opcommon.cpp and am now uncertain whether I should change the patch.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been helpful if you had posted code snippets from 4.1.1 also. `ifield->field.name` suggests that *field* itself is a member of the struct *InstField* and that *field* is also a struct with a member *name* (could be any struct, not necessarily of type Field). `ifield->name` on the other hand suggests that *name* itself is a member of the struct *InstField* (by Inheritance) and is **not a member of a member**. You need to look at the part of 4.1.1 where InstField is defined. It's probably different than this definition which you got from 4.3.

Comment: That's what's baffling me, the 4.1.1 declaration for Field and InstField are identical. The file has not been changed. I did a diff -s and got "are identical" back.